# Аналог --ask-vault-pass и --vault-password-file в файле с переменными для Ansible

Tags: linux, администрирование, config, ansible

Когда запускаю плейбук, в котором есть зашифрованные переменные - приходится указывать ключ `--ask-vault-pass`, чтобы меня спросили пароль или `--vault-password-file`, если он уже где-то лежит в открытом виде.

Вопрос: как эти ключи прописать в том же `*.yml` файле с зашированными переменными, чтобы ансибл сам на них натыкался когда нужно и сам всё делал вместо меня?

**UPD1.**

Как я хочу чтобы было:

vault-file-v1.yml:

```
ask_vaul_pass: yes
$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
1231231321321123123121321321
1231123123121321321321321321
```

vault-file-v2.yml:

```
vault_password_file: /path/to/pass.txt
$ANSIBLE_VAULT;1.1;AES256
1231231321321123123121321321
1231123123121321321321321321
```

ubuntu 16.04
ansible 2.4.1.0

Comment: А какой смысл в том, чтобы шифровать переменные паролем, который находится в этом же файле? Или я неверно понял вашу затею?

Comment: @D-side, потому что в переменные можно зашить всё что угодно, в том числе и пароль удалённого хоста. Добавил пример как я хочу видеть всю конструкцию.

Comment: Из коробки такой фичи нет, да и самостоятельно тоже, поэтому вам сюда: [create new feature request](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/new). Хотя мне кажется, зарубят.

Comment: @AK, хреново. Оформи как ответ, я галку поставлю.